# How to automatically resize span circle in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i am creating a react project and Im trying to add some circles to my page (5), i have created them with a fixed size, i cant find the way to resize them as per the window size when I minimize the browser the circles remain the same weight and lenght.

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
.y_dot{
    position: absolute;
    width: 336px;
    height: 336px;
    left: -5%;
    bottom: -10%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #EBD510;

}
```

```html
<div className="Circle_App">
        <h1 className="appHeader"> Welcome</h1>
        <div>
            <span class="b_dot"></span>
            <span class="g_dot"></span>
            <span class="p_dot"></span>
            <span class="y_dot"></span>
            <span class="o_dot"></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

The CSS configuration of other spans is preety much the same it just change the position or size of the circle.

Does anyone has a hint on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either vh (viewport height) or vw (viewport width) rather than px to make your value depend on viewport size.

```
// will set height and width to 
// 5% of window’s width
.y_dot {
    height: 5vw;
    width: 5vw;
}
```

Alternative way is to use media queries to create rules that apply once window is of certain size.

```
// will set height and width of dot to 
// 300px when screen is smaller than 600px.
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .y_dot {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

Comment: The implementation of viewport worked, Thanks! I didnt knew it.